# Can i deactivate a certain part of javascript from the browser?

Tags: javascript

A friend of mine programmed a website, using a tool from "1und1". The problem is, that, while you use this tool to easy create a website, you do not have any direct access to the code.

Now he did something stupid. He created a function, that relocates you, based on the language of you browser. This function however always relocates the user, no matter what language your browser has and this website never stops loading. Ones it is finished, it loads again.

My first intention was, to use the noscript-addon for Chrome, however the tool to edit this part also uses Javascript... So if i use noscript, this infinite reloading-problem is fixed temporary, but i cannot fix the problem once and for all!

Is there any way of only deactivating a certain script-part of the head-tag and not all of them?

Thank you all.

**edit**:
This is the Script in question:

```
//<![CDATA[
// The language of the browser as an orientation for the language of
// the user
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
// The current adress of the user
var adress = document.location.href;

if(adress == thisSite && userLang.match("de")) {
    // german
    window.location.href = '/deutsch/start/';
} else {
    // fallback (english)
    window.location.href = '/english/home/';
}
//]]>
```

Comment: It really depends on how that function is implemented. In the worst case you'll have to use an external man-in-the-middle proxy tool called Fiddler with a custom rule to cut out the script tag. Show that script code, it should be small, otherwise post only the relevant part where redirection occurs.

Comment: I edited the code into the question

Comment: 1und1, should provide you with a method to directly access the content of your site (e.g. ftp, some control console, etc.). Use this method to directly change the file, or database, which is storing the content being served. Without more specific information it is difficult to say exactly what method this is. You say " you do not have any direct access to the code".  While possible, it is unlikely that there is no other method of accessing the code. If that were the case, their Customer Support would have to handle lots of calls from people like your friend where some other access is needed.

Comment: Call 1und1's customer service and have them solve the problem: '0721-9609756 * for Service "1 & 1 Personal Advisor'  Their website states you get a 'Personal Advisor'. In addition they state that they provide 24/7 service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, after trying a whole night, for everyone, who has a similar problem, this is how i fixed this.

You HAVE to call 1und1 or use there live-chat for this. They take some time to fix it, because the person, you are speaking to, also has no access to the code. They then give it to the development team, wich is fixing it.

However, if you want to prevent any problem like that, i can just recommend you, to not use this tool! This tool gives you all things you don't want and even in the expert section they want to "improve" your code, by correcting it, wich led to my "infinit-recursion-problem".

If you are wondering, he entered the following:

```
else if(adress == thisSite) {
    // fallback (english)
    window.location.href = '/english/home/';
}
```

but it deleted the if-clause, because it said, it was unnecessary and he didn't even recognized it, until it was too late.

Therefor i recommend you: "Do not use this kind of tools, if you have any other way to do this (like Wordpress or Joomla or even a friend, who can barely code)".

Answer (score -1):

Open chromes developer tool. CTRL + SHIFT + I
go to the Elements tab
Find the peice of code you want to remove, right click it, select "Edit as html", remove/edit what you want to remove/edit, click somewhere else and it should affect the page accordingly.

Comment: It won't help to prevent the infinite redirection loop because there won't be enough time to delete the script element.

Comment: wOxxOm is correct. If you delete that part, you have to stop loading the website. this means you have to reload, to see try again and than it will load again, wich catches you in an infinite loop ;)

Answer (score -2):

You could go to the F12 menu and look under the elements tab. This houses all the current html/scripts/styling etc of the web page. Look for the script in question and just delete it, however, this is only a temporary local fix while on the page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It won't help to prevent the infinite redirection loop because there won't be enough time to delete the script element.

Comment: You can do it while the page is loading possibly, depending of course on how quickly it loads before reloading. Besides that there really isn't any way to get into the code unless you go through however your friend built the site. Why not just remove the function the way he put it in? What is he using to build the website?

Comment: Actually, script elements are executed immediately by browser so it doesn't matter how fast the page loads. This is why your answer doesn't work. And you're correct about the worst case, see my comment under the question itself.

Comment: Well, because of the script, you cant open the editor. If you use noscript, this infinite loop is gone, but you also can't use the editor with wich he put the function in, because it is based on Javascript.

Comment: Not always, it depends on how the scripts set up to execute. Especially if they are using a tool to build the site. Who knows what kind of junk gets tossed in there to make the building easier. I would agree that it sounds like they are being immediately executed if the page is in a constant reload. I am just throwing out any and all possibilities I can think of. I was unaware of that proxy tool Fiddler however, I am interested to look into that.

Comment: Now come's the funny question: Is there a "linux"-version of fiddler? I am just aware of the Windows-Version.

Comment: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono

That should help you set it up on linux

Comment: Well, i never used Fiddler for that. I injected Javascript as well as debuging, but never to "delete" a certain kind of Javascript part from the head. I will try my best and thanks for the help!